# Using Regex in mySQL query

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a database column with multiple names separated by line breaks like this:

```
jones, sue
jones, mark
```

I want to generate a query that keeps the first line and discards the rest, no matter how many lines there are...

I though I was getting close with this:

```
SELECT 
    name1 
FROM 
    email 
WHERE 
    name1  REGEXP '.*(\r\n)?'
```

but not quite...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, "\r\n", 1) ...
```

Test case:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("jones, sue\r\njones, mark", "\r\n", 1);
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX("jones, sue\r\njones, mark", "\r\n", 1) |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| jones, sue                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: hmmmm. thanks, but that doesn't seem to work... Is it possible that \n and \r (tried both...) don't work with my particular data? the column is utf-8 encoded...

Comment: @C.Lamb - I added a test case.  If you still have troubles, please provide your failing case.  (ascii/latin1/utf8 -- all work the same _in this example_.)